# How to send messages from file in Jmeter thread wise

Tags: java, jmeter, load, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have one file which contains 100 messages,one message in one line. I have 10 threads and each thread should pick one message from file and sent it to given address. Message should not be sent duplicate by any thread. Here i have 10 threads, so 1 thread should be responsible for sending 10 messages.

Answer (score 0):

Normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for this form of parameterization.

1. Add CSV Data Set Config to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, now you can refer the line from CSV as `${message}` where required, each user will read its own line, no duplicates, when all lines are read - test will end.

   [image]

Another option is to use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile), however in this case the test will not stop, you will have to worry about setting the number of iterations yourself. Also `__StringFromFile()` function keeps the whole file in memory so it is not suitable for large data sets.